# Rails 3 & Strong Parameters, getting mass assignment errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, strong-parameters

I'm trying to use strong parameters in a single model in my Rails 3 project that has around 40-50 models.

I've done the following, but when I try to create or update an instance of this model, I get the same error regarding mass assignment, as below, which shows every field of the model.

I've tried removing the `accepted_nested_attributes_for` from the model and restarting the webserver, but it didn't have an effect on the error I'm receiving.

**config/application.rb**

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

**app/models/my_service.rb** (concatenated for brevity)

```
class CallService < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  belongs_to :account
  has_many :my_service_chargeables
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :my_forward_schedules, allow_destroy: true


  validates  :start_date, :username, :account_id, :plan_id, presence: true
  audited associated_with: :account

  scope :enabled, where(enabled: true)
  scope :within, lambda{|month| where(start_date: (month.beginning_of_month..month.end_of_month))}

end
```

**app/controllers/my_services_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @my_service = MyService.find(params[:id])
  if @my_service.update_attributes(permitted_params.my_service)
    flash[:success] = "Service Updated"
    redirect_to @my_service
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
def permitted_params
  @permitted_params ||= PermittedParams.new(current_user, params)
end
```

**app/models/permitted_params.rb**

```
class PermittedParams < Struct.new(:user, :params)
  def my_service
    if user && user.role?(:customer)
      params.require(:my_service).permit(*service_customer_attributes)
    else
      params.require(:my_service).permit!
    end
  end

  def service_customer_attributes
    [:timeout, :pin, :day]
  end
end
```

**ERROR WHEN UPDATING**

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in MyServicesController#update

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: account_id, plan_id, start_date, username
```

I've run a debugger to confirm the code hits the `params.require(:my_service).permit!` line from the `PermittedParams` class, yet this exception still keeps getting thrown, when as far as I can tell, there should be nothing causing this model to require declaring attributes as attr_accessible's.

Can anyone shed some light on this behavior?

I'm using gem versions (from my **Gemfile.lock**):

```
strong_parameters (0.2.0)
rails (3.2.11)
```

Comment: Just out of interest have you not thought about adding `attr_accessible :account_id, :plan_id, :start_date, :username` to your model. As I am aware you know what this error `Can't mass-assign protected attributes` does usually mean. By using `attr_accessible` it takes a list of attributes that will be accessible. All other attributes will be protected. May also want to take a read at this - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of using the strong parameters gem, as it's meant to handle the protection of what user can set which attributes through the controllers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your exact use case is, but doing `params.require(:my_service).permit!` still seems like a bad idea here, at the very least someone could still override your model's PK. Rather than `params.require(:my_service).permit!` why not do:

```
params.require(:my_service).permit(:timeout, :pin, :day, :account_id,
  :plan_id, :start_date, :username)
```

Or keep these in another array and merge them with your existing `service_customer_attributes` to keep it DRY.

This would take care of your mass assignment error, and will be more secure and more explicit.